# D3: Creating scatter plot for multiple values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot, data-visualization

I am completely new to d3.
I have the following CSV:

```
HeaderAttempts  HeaderGoals FreekickAttempts    FreekickGoals   Team
5                     2             3                 2         Team A
2                     2             12                1         Team A
8                     2             13                5         Team B
4                     3             6                 2         Team B
7                     2             10                1         Team C
6                     5             13                7         Team C
8                     7             9                 3         Team C
```

I am trying to create a scatter plot where x axis will have attempts and y axis will have the goals.
i have been able to create a scatter plot for the header attempts and goals by using the following code:

```
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);


var color = d3.scale.category10();

var axisNames = { 
                    HeaderAttempts: 'HeaderAttempts', 
                   HeaderGoals: 'HeaderGoals', 
                    FreekickAttempts: 'FreekickAttempts', 
                    FreekickGoals: 'FreekickGoals' 
                };

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


d3.csv("FootballData.csv", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.HeaderAttempts = +d.HeaderAttempts;
    d.HeaderGoals = +d.HeaderGoals;
    d.FreekickAttempts = +d.FreekickAttempts;
    d.FreekickGoals = +d.FreekickGoals;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.HeaderAttempts; })).nice();
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.HeaderGoals; })).nice();



  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("x", width)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("attempts");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("goals")

var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")  // tooltip code
   .attr("class", "tooltip")
   .style("opacity", 0);

 var circlesH = svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 3.5)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.HeaderAttempts); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.HeaderGoals); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.Team); })
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
         tooltip.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", 1.0);
         tooltip.html(d.HeaderAttempts+" ,"+ d.HeaderGoals)
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 18) + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
         tooltip.transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style("opacity", 0);
      });

var circlesF = svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 3.5)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.FreekickAttempts); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.FreekickGoals); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.Team); })
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
         tooltip.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", 1.0);
         tooltip.html(d.FreekickAttempts+" ,"+ d.FreekickGoals)
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 18) + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
         tooltip.transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style("opacity", 0);
      });     

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });


  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);


  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });



  d3.selectAll("[name=v]")
  .on("change", function() {
      var selected = this.value;
      display = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";


  svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .filter(function(d) {return selected == d.Team;})
      .attr("display", display);
      });


});
</script>

<div id="filter">
    <b>team Filter:</b>
        <br>
    <input name='v' value="Team A" type="checkbox" checked>Team A
    </input>
        <br>
    <input name="v" value="Team B" type="checkbox" checked >Team B
    </input>
        <br>
    <input name="v" value="Team C" type="checkbox" checked >Team C
    </input>
  </div>
```

I know this wasnt going to work but had to give it a shot. 
Now i have no idea how to proceed.
This is actually a truncated data and i still have 4 more columns:
PenaltyAttempts, PenaltyGoals, CornerAttempts, CornerGoals

Comment: can you paste your full code here...

Comment: I edited the existing question for the code. plz have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach of making separate graphs and overlapping in this is not really correct.

Better way is to make your dataset as per your requirement.

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.HeaderAttempts = +d.HeaderAttempts;
    d.HeaderGoals = +d.HeaderGoals;
    d.FreekickAttempts = +d.FreekickAttempts;
    d.FreekickGoals = +d.FreekickGoals;
    var attempts = d.HeaderAttempts + d.FreekickAttempts;//calculate all attempts of a team
    var goals = d.HeaderGoals + d.FreekickGoals;//calculate all goals of a team
    //make your data set like this
    all.push({
      team: d.Team,
      attempts: attempts,
      goals: goals
    });
  });
```

Then use this all object to make your domains

```
  x.domain(d3.extent(all, function(d) { return d.attempts; })).nice();
  y.domain(d3.extent(all, function(d) { return d.goals; })).nice();
```

Even points can be made easily like this:

```
  svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(all)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 3.5)
      .attr("cx", function(d) {console.log(d,"s");return x(d.attempts); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.goals); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.team); })
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/q2ch2JCkRlgUxGjm4Y6b?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the effort Cyril :) I really appreciate that. But I wasn't looking for a sum of  d.HeaderAttempts + d.FreekickAttempts;
& d.HeaderGoals + d.FreekickGoals;
I wanted to have a plot for (HeaderAttempts,HeaderGoals) and (FreekickAttempts,FreekickGoals) on the same graph. Like having a dual-axis for two different sets.
I apologize for the misunderstanding.

Comment: OK i understand that you want to make separate graphs of these combination (HeaderAttempts,HeaderGoals) and (FreekickAttempts,FreekickGoals)  can you put a screen shot of how the dual axis will look...or how your graph should look